How does Firebase collect and actively report custom logs?
Can the logs collected by Firebase include custom logs? If so, how to collect them? For example, I want to directly and actively report custom content through Firebase after the application is opened or when the network connection is monitored.
In addition, is it necessary to make other additional configurations in the console?And , how to view custom logs on the console?
I hope that the sample code can be achieved, and if it is necessary to make relevant configurations in the Firebase console, I hope that there can be complete operation steps.
